# Fallo con chatterbot

Tags: python

He intentado juntar la librería de pywhatkit con la de chatterbot, para hacer un bot de WhatsApp. Cuando he hecho algunas pruebas solo con la librería de Chatterbot me sale el siguiente error.
Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo me alegraría el dia. Saludos y gracias

```
    File "chatbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    chat = ChatBot('cctmx')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/storage_adapter.py", line 21, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ésto en la terminal:

```
python -m spacy download en
```